# Best practices for detecting when "user is typing" for chat functionalities?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, chat, pubnub

I am currently using PubNub to handle the realtime aspects of chat, and plan to change a `PNChannel`'s `state` when a user is typing or has completed typing.

My question relates more to the client side of how something like an `isTyping` state can be measured . Since every tap on the screen keyboard is bound to have some space of time in between, I was wondering if there is a "best practice" way to either measure the time gaps between screen taps to understand whether a user is typing (for example, a slow typer versus a faster typer) versus when the user has actually stopped typing?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `NSTimer` in combination with detecting keystrokes. It's up to you to decide how much time can go by after the last detected keystroke and still consider it "typing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up in these [delegate methods of `UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate)

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender //method fires when u start begining typing anything in a textfield
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField // method fires whenever u type anything in a textfield- returns character wise
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)sender // fires when u finished typing stuffs in a textfield.
```

Hope this helps